# Azure ADB2C Claims in an Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-static-web-app

I am a little stumped on getting claims to pass from Azure AD B2C to my Static Web App.

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-user-flow). All I need to do is go to Application claims, choose the ones I want and click on save.

I have all of them checked.

[image: application claims]

I registered an application in my ADB2C tenant. Then configured an OpenID Connect Provider in Azure Static Web Apps.

I can sign in to my App using users in the ADB2C Tenant. I have a page that I set up to get the claims and all I get is this.

[image: application results]

This is my App Manifest

```json
{
    "id": "947e0f27-54f8-4fd7-8d47-7138ec829e49",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "25a72c46-1be1-445e-9ed1-fbf89732c9ea",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2022-08-16T17:23:28Z",
    "description": null,
    "certification": null,
    "disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": "https://seanwoodwardwebb2c.b2clogin.com/seanwoodwardwebb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin1/oauth2/v2.0/logout",
    "name": "SWA Test",
    "notes": null,
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [],
        "accessToken": [],
        "saml2Token": []
    },
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": null,
            "endDate": "2023-02-16T18:23:56.247Z",
            "keyId": "886381a9-74d8-4176-8921-e34299f52b13",
            "startDate": "2022-08-16T17:23:56.247Z",
            "value": null,
            "createdOn": "2022-08-16T17:24:00.1757229Z",
            "hint": "4pA",
            "displayName": "Dev"
        }
    ],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "seanwoodwardwebb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "https://jwt.ms",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://gentle-water-027065a10.1.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/adb2c/callback",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://gentle-water-027065a10-staging.centralus.1.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/adb2c/callback",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://gentle-water-027065a10-dev.centralus.1.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/adb2c/callback",
            "type": "Web"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

This is my code base https://github.com/woodman231/az-swa-b2c-demo

I have a sneaky suspicion that I need to modify this app registration to some degree, but I am not sure what I might need to do. Also I am not sure if ADB2C is not providing the claims, or if the claims are being dropped with the SWA proxy. Any help would be appreciated.

Part of me believes that this could be an issue with the SWA Proxy. Because if I run my SignupSignIn Policy with this app registration and use https://jwt.ms as the Reply URL...

[image: Run User Flow Screen Shot]

I do get all of the claims. So why are the claims not showing up in the /.auth/me endpoint?

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom?tabs=openid-connect) all I need to do is provide the client id and client secret from my app registration as well as the wellknown openid config document. The wellknown one that I am supplying is the one associated with my adb2c policy, and not just the generic one for my tenant so you would think that would be more specific and detailed. So if the claims are provided by the jwt, why are the claims not being copied when going to /.auth/login/<PROVIDER_NAME_IN_CONFIG>/callback, and thus not available at /.auth/me?

[image: jwtms has claims]

Comment: Is the app manifest the audience or the consumer? or both?

Comment: @smurtagh I actually don't know. I am thinking the consumer or sure. It is the only app registration that I have associated with this application at this time.

Comment: Since you get all claims at jwt.ms, this is an issue with azure static web apps auth module, which is set to only map certain claims. (I don’t know if it’s adjustable).